# How to Add Row at Last position and Remove Row from current position In DataGridview in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working on vb./net.
 in grid view Every have two button Like + and - if user Click + Then One row need to add at last position and if user click - then one row need to remove from Current position

I have try following code but it will give me an error

```
Private count As Integer = 1
    Private Sub dgvSourcePath_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvSourcePath.CellContentClick
        If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
            dgvSourcePath.Rows.Insert(count)
        End If
        If e.ColumnIndex = 3 Then
            count -= 1
            dgvSourcePath.Rows.RemoveAt(count)
        End If
        If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
            OpenSourceFileDialog.ShowDialog()
            If Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                dgvSourcePath.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = OpenSourceFileDialog.FileName
            End If
        End If
        dgvSourcePath.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Gee, if only there was some way that we could find out what the error message is and exactly what line the error occurs on.

Comment: The `CellContentClick` event gives you the index of the row that was clicked.  You should be using that index when you remove a row.  As for adding, why use `Insert` when `Add` specifically adds to the end of the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
      Private Sub dgvdatos_CellContentClick(sender As DataGridView, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvdatos.CellContentClick
Try

  dgvdatos.EndEdit()

  If TypeOf (sender.CurrentCell) Is DataGridViewButtonCell Then

    If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
      dgvdatos.Rows.Insert(sender.RowCount - 1)
    End If
    If e.ColumnIndex = 3 And sender.Rows.Count > 1 Then
      count -= 1
      dgvdatos.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
    End If
    If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
      OpenSourceFileDialog.ShowDialog()
      If DialogResult.OK Then
        dgvdatos.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = OpenSourceFileDialog.FileName
      End If
    End If
    dgvdatos.Refresh()
  End If
Catch ex As Exception

  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

End Sub